# Mount old home as actual home

Tags: partitioning, mount, home-directory

I'm new on ubuntu and I had Ubuntu 14.04 with Unity.
I had home on separate partition (not decrypted).
Today I install Ubuntu Gnome 15.10 on old boot partition. I want now mount old home as actual home. 
I found this link with similar procedure:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving
Is this what I should do If I want mount this partition as my home?
This is what how it is now:

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="...335" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="000627f7-01"
/dev/sda5: UUID="...5c2" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="000627f7-05"
/dev/sda6: UUID="...2ab" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="000627f7-06"
```

/dev/sda6 is my old home

[this is how it looks in nautilus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ULxJ.png)
And I have different user name now... it is problem?

Please help me...

UPDATE:
Yes I want step by step answer please.
This are additional information you want:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=e32e4178-b039-41e1-a591-4ca3c739f335 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=92a0ca7e-064c-44f1-a48b-38360928b5c2 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

and

```
uid=1000(spajdo) gid=1000(spajdo) groups=1000(spajdo),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),113(lpadmin),130(sambashare)
```

Old username was michal

Comment: Best to mount /home during install. You also may have to update ownership & permissions on that partition. This includes copy to new partition, so you can skip that part: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving

Comment: Please provide us with more information if you want to get full step by step answer. Add output of this commands `cat /etc/fstab` from new OS. Also add both username information (old and new) using `id -a username`. Do you need something to be saved in new home folder?

Comment: c0rp - I updated my question... can you help me please?

Comment: How big is your old home folder? I think the easiest way would be just copy everything. But before I provide you command to copy, could you add output of `ls -l /media/spajdo/90aeb766-0497-4557-a922-d6ddffb022ab/michal`. If you don't feel comfortable with copying let me know.

Comment: No, copy is not a way. I had separate partition for reason of reinstall system, but data do not touch. And my old home is too big... Old home has 290GB and new system padtition has only 25GB

Answer (score -1):

To change the home directory of a user, do:

```
sudo usermod -m -d /newhome/username username
```

then give it the mount point of your old hard drive.

So, you do not want your home to be what it is currently. "/home/spajdo/"
instead, you would like it to be "media/spajdo/90aeb766-0497-4557-a922-d6ddffb022ab/michal/"  and whatever your user-name is. 
 so you might do

```
sudo usermod -m -d /media/spajdo/90aeb766-0497-4557-a922-d6ddffb022ab/michal/  `whoami`
```

you can read more about this in the manpage. `man usermod`

Comment: Now my home is /home/spajdo/ and my old home is /media/spajdo/90aeb766-0497-4557-a922-d6ddffb022ab/michal/
And I want /media/spaj..../michal/ as /home/spajdo/ how can I use your command please...

Comment: joh, your answer is incorrect and unclear. I downvoted it

Comment: @c0rp are your happy yet? Or, can you be more specific? do you have something useful to point out? This line: "I want now mount old home as actual home" is the bassis for my answer.

Comment: I'm guessing old home is mounted manually, because it is mounted to `/media...`. So if you just move home without pointing it in the fstab it will lead to a problem after reboot